# turn a dict that may contain a pandas dataframe to several dicts

Tags: python, hash-map, pandas

I have a dict that may be 'infinitely' nested and contain several pandas DataFrame's (all the DataFrame's have the same amount of rows).

I want to create a new dict for each row in the DataFrame's, with the row being transformed to a dict (the key's are the column names) and the rest of the dictionary staying the same.

Note: I am not making a cartesian product between the rows of the different DataFrame's.

I have an example in my SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52513662/turn-a-dict-that-may-contain-a-pandas-dataframe-to-several-dicts)

here is what i came up with:

```
import pandas as pd
from copy import deepcopy
from functools import partial

def map_keys_by_type(d, typ, path=None):
    for k,v in d.items():
        p = path.copy() if path else []
        p.append(k)
        if isinstance(v, typ):
            yield p
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from map_keys_by_type(v, typ, p)

def nested_get(nested_key, input_dict):
    internal_dict_value = input_dict
    for k in nested_key:
        internal_dict_value = internal_dict_value.get(k, None)
        if internal_dict_value is None:
            return None
    return internal_dict_value

def nested_set(dic, keys, value):
    for key in keys[:-1]:
        dic = dic.setdefault(key, {})
    dic[keys[-1]] = value

def dup_dicts(keys, iter_of_values, init_dict):
    for values in iter_of_values:
        init_dict = deepcopy(init_dict)
        [nested_set(init_dict, key, value) for key, value in zip(keys, values)]
        yield init_dict

if __name__ == '__main__':
    keys = list(map_keys_by_type(d, pd.DataFrame))
    dfs = map(partial(nested_get, input_dict=d), keys)
    dfs_as_dicts = map(partial(pd.DataFrame.to_dict, orient='records'), dfs)
    iter_of_dicts = dup_dicts(keys,zip(*dfs_as_dicts), d)
```

any improvements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the code works as intended.

Firstly, let me tell you that your code looks very pythonic - this is a huge plus.

## My comments:

**Introduction**

You state that

> I have a dict that may be 'infinitely' nested

Keep in mind that since you seem to be doing recursive calls your [stack is limited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3323013/3809977) hence is your ability to retrive nested dict.

**map_keys_by_type**

Argument `d` is not informative, try using `dic` (if you want to follow your change `type`->`typ`) or `dictionary`.

Although, this is not extreamly important you might consider changing `p` to something more informative. When I've read the code first time I almost immediacy forgot what this variable stands for. However, as I said this is not very important because the function is small.

**nested_get**

This bit

```
for k in nested_key:
    internal_dict_value = internal_dict_value.get(k, None)
    if internal_dict_value is None:
        return None
```

in my opinion would be clearer if you did:

```
if k not in internal_dict_value:
    return None
else:
    internal_dict_value = internal_dict_value[k]
```

`not in` shows your intention directly.

Everything else looks okay for me.